# Not sure how to contain text that I have put over an image

Tags: html, css

I have put some text over an image, the image adjusts based on the size of the window, however, as I have put the text over image using absolute the text will overflow out of the image and I am unsure of how to fix this.I want the text to fit based on the image as a container to make it more responsive but I am unsure of how to do so. After doing some searching I realise it is because I used positioning to place my text over the image. In this case I am still unsure of how to fix it.

```
<main class="main-page">
            <section class="main-area">
              <img src="Images/Horizontal image.jpg" alt ="main image" class ="main-image">
              <div class = "main-area-text">
                <h1 class = "main-area-header">30% off This Weekend!</h1>
                <div class="main-area-description">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit blanditiis dolorum suscipit, expedita voluptatem quo doloribus! Unde qui, deserunt iste mollitia, veniam maxime quo corporis nam reiciendis vitae modi sunt?
                  Laudantium inventore laboriosam doloremque ullam perferendis fugit repudiandae, eum dicta distinctio architecto soluta! Repudiandae, delectus. Aperiam esse dolorem blanditiis, sit voluptatum laudantium hic soluta. Cupiditate enim similique facilis ut pariatur.
                  Totam incidunt soluta deleniti cumque neque veritatis sed eveniet iusto ducimus dolor explicabo quisquam, nemo autem voluptatum maiores voluptate quam possimus aut sequi ipsa beatae nam provident. Tempora, doloribus quasi?
                </div>  
              </div>
            </section>
```

```
.main-page {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 0;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    /*border: 2px dashed red;*/
  }
  
  .main-page .main-area {
    position:relative;
  }

  .main-area .main-image{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    /*padding: 8px;*/
    border-radius:25px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-height:250px;
    width:100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    }

  .main-area .main-area-text{
    position:absolute;
    color:white;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    display:flex; 
    flex-wrap:wrap;
  }

  .main-area-text .main-area-header{
    font-size:2em;
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-bottom:25px;
  }

  .main-area .main-area.description{
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    flex-basis:auto;
  }
```

I tried containing it using text-overflow but from what I understand it is not sure where the bottom of the container is but is aware of the width. I tried using flex-shrink, but from my understanding its that it only applies to multiple containers(?) to fit horizontally. The course I am doing requires me to mainly use CSS to get an understanding of it so I am unable to use things like boostrap

Comment: You could use a background image for the `section` and remove the actual `img` element itself. That way you can use more conventional flow for the text without resorting to `absolute` positioning

Comment: Thanks! Googled put text over image and the absolute positioning ones were the main ones I was showed. Had no idea that background image was a thing : ' )

Comment: Excellent! Glad I was able to shine a little light on the subject for you. Good luck